# Getting the number of "lists" returned by split() in python

Tags: python

So in order for a different task I wanted to get the number of lists returned by the split() function from a file of commands. The file, `command.txt` has below entries:

```
ps -a
free
```

And the code that I came up with to convert it into list and get the number of list is:

```
with open('command.txt', 'r') as file:
     #for i, v in enumerate(file): #I can get the line counts.
     #    pass
     #print i+1

     for line in file:
         word = line.split()
         print word
         print len(word)
```

The output of this code is:

> ['ps', '-a']
>
> 2
>
> ['free']
>
> 1

Rather I want the output to be just 2. Since `word` has 2 lists, ['ps', '-a'] and ['free']. Could anyone please suggest how I can modify or come up with the appropriate code.

Comment: `split` has nothing to do with what you want to accomplish; you're trying to count lines.

Comment: Well I want not the count of lines in the file rather the count returned by `line.split()`

Comment: That does not match your question.

Comment: `word` has exactly one list per iteration. As @KlausD. points out, your question as stated is really just asking for the line count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments above, it sounds like you are just asking for a line count. Since you're already looping through the file, just add a counter:

```
n = 0
with open('command.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        word = line.split()
        print word
        n += 1
print n
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to count lines.  A way to do this without looping through:

```python
with open('command.txt','r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
lines = len(data)
print lines
```

However, you will have to remove the "\n" from all of the lines except the last.